# export default class App extends React.Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, export, expo, extends

i am a begginer of expo and i encountered this in the app.js file

export default class App extends React.Component

Can anyone explain what this line of code actually mean? i cant understand this

Comment: There's a long way ahead of you... I would recommend reading a toturial about JavaScript's basics, and Nofe

Comment: can you give any link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You should tag this with react-native instead of react, react-native is used with Expo for creating mobile apps, the 'native' part refers to how it uses native components from either IOS or Android which are written in Swift and Java respectively.

However, I can tell you that what that line of code is doing is exporting the class `App` so that other files can import it. `App` extends `React.Component` which gives the class access to methods and lifecycle hooks. It's basic ES6 Javascript, if you're going to be writing React then you're going to want to start with the basics of Javascript including ES6.